# Add aditional labels to colorbar in Matlab

Tags: matlab, axis-labels, colorbar

I am using Matlab (Version R2013b) and have produced a gridded map of Europe with Julian day values for each grid square (well not strictly Julian days; but rather days from the 1st of January. i.e. 3rd of January is 3, 5th of January is 5 etc).
I plotted this data and then used `colorbar` to illustrate the day number being displayed. This results in a colorbar with the number intervals of the right hand side of the colorbar.
Is it possible to add additional information on the left hand side of the colorbar, showing 'February' around the '60' mark and May around the 150 mark? I'm thinking that i'll need to create another axis on the colorbar to do this?

This is the code I use to make the plot:

```
surf(meshlon,meshlat,wrf_data(:,:,1),'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','k');view(2);
    hold on;
    %Plot jd
    surf(meshlon,meshlat,budburst(:,:,cordexcntr)),'linestyle','none';view(2);
    %reduce the size of the plot to encompass the data
    lat1=wrf_rlat(1);
    latend=wrf_rlat(length(wrf_rlat));
    set(gca,'YLim',[lat1 latend])
    lon1=wrf_rlon(1);
    lonend=wrf_rlon(length(wrf_rlon));
    set(gca,'XLim',[lon1 lonend])
   
    %get rid of labels
    set(gca,'xticklabel',[])
    set(gca,'yticklabel',[])
    box on
    caxis([0 365]);
    h=colorbar;
    ylabel(h, 'Julian Day of Budburst');
```

And this is what the plot looks like:
[image]

Comment: I think it would help if you included a short bit of stand-alone code that creates your color bar. Then it is easier to show you how to modify that to obtain your desired result. Also including a screen shot of your figure window might make clearer what you have so far.

Comment: Can you replace the numbers with dates?

Comment: Take a look at [yticks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yticks.html) I think that's what you are looking for

Comment: You can directly modify the ticks of the colorbar itself to the description you desire. Alternatively, `text()` and `annotate()` can be used to plot text anywhere within a figure window.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Done. I have updated my post

Comment: @Nathan: Do you mean to create a date vector for the entire year and then use that as input to the colorbar via yticks?

Comment: @Adriaan: I want to fully automate the process, as I'll be making alot of these plots.

Comment: R2013b?!? That's practically ancient by MATLAB standards, especially since the overhaul of the graphics engine in R2016b. It's unlikely that people will have an old enough version to test on for you, but more importantly: you are missing out on many of the fancy new features in graphics which are potentially useful for you. Do consider upgrading to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the tick marks of the color bar to the days corresponding to the first day of each month, and then change the corresponding tick labels with a suitable string. For example:

```matlab
ndays = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
% Where to put the tick marks:
ticks = [1,cumsum(ndays(1:end-1))];
% What to put at each tick mark:
labels = {'Jan 1','Feb 1','Mar 1','Apr 1','May 1','Jun 1','Jul 1','Aug 1','Sep 1','Oct 1','Nov 1','Dec 1'}; 

caxis([1,sum(ndays)]); % [1,365], not [0,365]
h = colorbar;
set(h,'Ticks',ticks,'TickLabels',labels);
ylabel(h,'Julian Day of Budburst');
```

(Note that this was not tested in R2013b, the MATLAB graphics engine has had a big overhaul since then, which changed some of the graphics capabilities.)

Comment: To automate this a bit easier, use [`eomday(2019,1:12)`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eomday.html) instead of writing out the days in a month. Leap years are automatically taken care of that way.